# Google tag manager error with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a issue after integration Google-tag-manager code to my web site: "GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX  (index):336(anonymous function) (index):336(anonymous function)".
We suppose it is related that this script is not directly specified https protocol, and therefore the browser interprets the request as unsafe. This issue happend only Google Chrome. On FireFox everything ok. How it can be fixed?

I have read that issue can occur due to AdBlock, but when I off if, issue wasn't resolved.

Comment: can you share the site?

Comment: https://www.exness.com/ now tag manager is off

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [*Setup and installation*](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en#AddingTheContainerSnippet) you may try to **verify or troubleshoot** your installation with:

> - [*Tag Manager's Preview Mode*](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056)
> - [*Tag Assistant Chrome extension*](https://support.google.com/tagassistant)

[image: Tag Assistant Chrome extension]